# Python Dataframe: Add element to multiple cells with condition

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, series

Hi lets say I have a dataframe and I want to add text to selected cells with condition. The condition is that the cells are not nan:

The dataframe:

```
index Column1

1      nan 
2      name1
3      name2
4      name4
```

I am only interested in cells 2 to 3 and check if they are not nan I want to add a string like "str_2_add"

Final should look like this:

```
index Column1

1      nan 
2      name1 str_2_add
3      name2 str_2_add
4      name4
```

What is the best way to do this. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`pd.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [`pd.Series.notnull`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notnull.html):

```
df.loc[df['Column1'].notnull() & df['index'].isin([2, 3]), 'Column1'] += ' str_2_add'

print(df)

   index          Column1
0      1              NaN
1      2  name1 str_2_add
2      3  name2 str_2_add
3      4            name4
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [where](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.Series.where.html) method. (or mask)

```
#these are equivalent
df.where(df == "nan", df + "str_2_add")
df.mask(df != "nan", df + "str_2_add")
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, I want to do this to only selected rows not all of them Only 2 and 3 as in my example.